# Sonarqube Out of Memory Error "JOURNAL_COPIER"

Tags: sonarqube, salesforce

I am trying to run CodeScanner, from the Bundle, with the Sonarqube which is installed.  I am trying to run against a large org and getting an out of memory error.  Any help will be most appreciated.

**Please see the extract from the log below:**

```
[sonar:sonar] 10:54:56.825 INFO  - Sensor CodeScan::File Indexer [codescan] (done) | time=1883ms
[sonar:sonar] 10:54:56.825 INFO  - Sensor CodeScan::Code Parser [codescan]

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "JOURNAL_COPIER"
[sonar:sonar] Exception in thread "CLEANUP_MANAGER" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
[sonar:sonar]   at java.util.ArrayList.<init>(ArrayList.java:152)
[sonar:sonar]   at com.persistit.CleanupManager.poll(CleanupManager.java:166)
[sonar:sonar]   at com.persistit.CleanupManager.runTask(CleanupManager.java:88)
[sonar:sonar]   at com.persistit.IOTaskRunnable.run(IOTaskRunnable.java:144)
[sonar:sonar]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[sonar:sonar] 10:55:52.137 WARN  - [JOURNAL_FLUSHER] WARNING Journal flush operation took 2,409ms last 8 cycles average is 301ms

BUILD FAILED
/Users/aporter/Downloads/codescan-bundler/codescan/runner/antbuild.xml:63: org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
```

Comment: Thank you G. Ann, but i am now getting another error - java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded.  Have been searching and people saying the same and increase the heap size.  I have increased to ANT_OPTS=-Xmx4048m still no joy.  I have a macbook Air with 8GB.  The org i am testing with is very large, is there a way to split into chunks?  Have you any ideas?  Thank you in advance

Comment: But you're not actually using Ant, are you? You need to set the OPTS for the analysis method you're using.

Comment: Apologies G. Ann for not understanding totally.  I am not a technical person, but have been dragged into prove this, as I want the dev team to start using CodeScanner as there are issues with what is being produced.  I have change the line "sonar.ce.javaOpts=-Xmx2014m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError" within the file codescan-bundler/sonarqube/confsonar.properties.  Is this the correct param to be changing.  thank you in advance

Comment: That is for the server. What is your analysis method?

Comment: I have followed the online instructions (https://www.code-scan.com/bundler/) and setup a project in Jenkins.  I entered the Salesforce parameters, then click on the build button.

Comment: G. Ann, can you please help?  I am a stuck and worried that my trial license is going to expire and will not be able to prove the tool

Comment: If you have a trial license then you should have access to pre-sales support. Contact CodeScanner.

Comment: I have now resolved this issue:-
- click on the job, then click on configure on the left
- After that scroll down to the bottom where the ant task for running the 'sonar' target is
- click on the advanced button
- change ‘=Xmx512m’ to '-Xmx2048m'
- Click ‘Build with Parameters’ on the left, then select build
The job then runs successfully